# Testing React Function was Called with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I have a React class which renders a child component called PersonalDetails. The code works fine, however I cannot get Jest to verify the saveData was called correctly when the Enter key is pressed in the field. I have mocked the saveData function passed to the PersonalDetails but the assertions fail (code condensed for brevity) on the mock:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: null
        };    
        this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
    }

    render() {        
        return (
            <div>
                <PersonalDetails name={this.state.name} saveData={this.saveData}/>;
                <OtherThing saveData={this.saveData}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    saveData(key, value){
        var d = {};
        d[key] = value;
        this.setState(d)
    }
}
```

The PersonalDetails module is as follows:

```
class PersonalDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    }

    render() {            
        return (
            <div>
                <input onKeyPress={this.handleNameChange}
                       defaultValue={this.props.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleNameChange(event) {
        if (event.nativeEvent.keyCode != 13) return;
        this.props.saveData('name',event.target.value)
    }
}
```

Jest test case in question:

```
it("saves data on change", function () {

    var saveData = jest.genMockFunction(); // mocking saveData
    const pdComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <PersonalDetails saveData={saveData} name="My Name"/>
    );

    var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
        pdComponent, 'input'
    );

    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(input);
    node.value = "New Name"; // As per FB tests
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(node, {target: {value: "New Name"}});
    TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(node, {key: "Enter", keyCode: 13, which: 13});
    expect(node.value).toBe("New Name"); // Passes
    // Fails
    expect(pdComponent.props.saveData).toBeCalledWith("New Name");
    // Also Fails
    expect(saveData).toBeCalledWith("New Name");

});
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: can you try to do `TestUtils.Simulate.input(...)`? Also the event data you want to supply might be incorrect. I'm currently also studying some jest use cases, yet there are only sparse docs available.

Comment: i tried input but it doesn't seem to achieve anything, the test still fails. I can't find any docs either

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Spy. A spy would be spying i.e keeping track.Using the Spy, you can check if the function was called or not.

Sample Code( Copied from the net)

```
var CompSpec = {
  displayName: "Comp",

  plop: function() {
    console.log("plop");
  },

  render: function() {
    this.plop();
    return React.DOM.div("foo");
  }
};

var stub = sinon.stub(CompSpec, "plop");
var Comp = React.createClass(CompSpec);
React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(Comp());

// plop() is properly stubbed, so you can
sinon.assert.called(stub); // pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this to my example? What is sinon?

Comment: Sinon Js is a JS Framework which provides Standalone test spies, stubs and mocks for JavaScript.
No dependencies, works with any unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is simple yet difficult to discover:

```
it('just an input test', () => {
    const keyPressAction = jest.fn(() => {
        console.log('key press');
    });

    const input = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<input type="text" onKeyPress={keyPressAction.bind(this)}/>);

    const inputNode: Element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(input);

    inputNode.setAttribute('value', 'test');
    TestUtils.Simulate.keyPress(inputNode, {key: "Enter", keyCode: 13, which: 13});

    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('test');
    expect(keyPressAction).toBeCalled();
});
```

Compare this with the solution in your question.

For the input element you use `onKeyPress` event, but in the test you simulate `keyDown` which can't work, just replace it with `keyPress` and the handler will be called.

Have a nice day!

Comment: i tried this but it's still not registering the function was called though i am certain it works correctly ( i can see it all working in the browser)